# What is this question asking? (integrals, derivatives)

Tags: integration, derivatives

The question is:

Let $G(x) = \int_{\cos(2x)}^{1/2} \arcsin(t) dt$. Find all $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ such that $\frac{d}{dx} G(x) = 0$.

Is it asking "for what values of x between 0 to $\pi/2$ is the derivative 0?" 
And if it is how would I proceed.

Comment: Hint: use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus to write down $G'(x)$, then solve for $G'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@amWhy noted the way of solving theoretically, but: $$G(x)=-\int_{0.5}^{\cos(2x)}\arcsin(t)dt$$ and so $$G'(x)=2\arcsin(\cos(2x))\sin(2x)$$ and now, we have:  $$\arcsin(\cos(2x))=0~~~\text{or}~~~\sin(2x)=0$$ If  $$\arcsin(\cos(2x))=0\Longrightarrow\cos(2x)=\sin(0)=0$$ and then $$\cos(2x)=0\longrightarrow2x=2k\pi\pm\pi/2,~~~k\in\Bbb Z$$ Now  pick up the values you are wanted to chose. And if $\sin(2x)=0$ then $$2x=k\pi,~~~k\in\Bbb Z$$. I think the common solutions which lie in the interval can be easily chosen.

[image]

Comment: nice work! +1 :-)

Comment: If $F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(t)dt$ then $F'(x)=g(b(x)) b'(x)-g(a(x))a'(x)$. In the above $G'(x)$ is missing derivative of $\cos(2x)$.

Comment: @Maesumi: Yes, you were right. I fixed it. Thanks for noting me that. +1000

Comment: Nice graphic! +1 if I could upvote again!

Comment: @amWhy: It is kind of you. I did it maybe the OP gets the solutions in the interval better.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Make use of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Given $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of $g(t)\,dt$, when evaluated, is a function of $x$, whose derivative is then *what* in terms of the integrand? (It is integrand, essentially, but expressed as function $g(x)$ of $x$ and no longer a function of $t$, given the bounds of integration.)

Then, yes, find the values of $x$ for which the derivative of the integral $g(x)= \frac {d}{dx}\left(G(x)\right)\,=\,0$.

Note that in evaluating your integral, and viewing it in terms of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $$G(x)=\int_{\cos(2x)}^{1/2} \arcsin(t)\,dt = -\int_{0.5}^{\cos(2x)}\arcsin(t)dt$$

so here, "$g(x)$" is really a function of $\cos(2x): g(\cos(2x))$, and so $$\frac{d}{dx}\,G(x)=2\arcsin(\cos(2x))\sin(2x)\tag{$\frac{d}{dx}G(x)$}$$

Now, $\frac{d}{dx}G(x)$ evaluates to $0$ when either $$\arcsin(\cos(2x)) = 0\tag {1}$$ or when $$\sin(2x) = 0\tag{2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did some handy jobs for the OP. +

Comment: This answer does not take into account the cos term.